# How does EXISTS return things other than all rows or no rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginning SQL programmer - I am getting most things, but not EXISTS.

It looks to me, and looks by the documentation, that an entire EXISTS statement returns a boolean value.

However, I see specific examples where it can be used and returns part of a table as opposed to all or none of it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNAME
FROM P    
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM SP Join S ON SP.SNO = S.SNO
    WHERE SP.PNO = P.PNO
    AND S.STATUS > 25
)
```

This query returns to me one value, the one that meets the criteria (S.Status > 25).

However, with other queries, it seems to return the whole table I am selecting from if even one of the rows in the EXISTS subquery is true.

How does one control this?

Comment: You used P.PNO in Exists block it means you compare for each row of the SP.If you remove this where condition then it returns all data even exists contain one row but it will return true.

Comment: Exists will evaluate the next query, if it returns at least one record, it will return true, otherwise it will return false, so it depends on your query after the exists keyword, you can post the other queries that is confusing you to explain how it works for that specific query.

Comment: Please post the `other queries` which return you entire tables data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries such as with EXISTS can either be correlated or non-correlated.

In your example you use a correlated subquery, which is usually the case with EXISTS. You look up records in SP for a given P.PNO, i.e. you do the lookup for each P record.

Without `SP.PNO = P.PNO` you would have a non-correlated subquery. I.e. the subquery no longer depends on the P record. It would return the same result for any P record (either a Status > 25 exists at all or not). Most often when this happens this is done by mistake (one forgot to relate the subquery to the record in question), but sometimes it is desired so.

Answer (score 3):

You have actually created a `Correlated subquery`. `Exists` predicate accepts a subquery as input and returns TRUE if the subquery returns **any** rows and FALSE otherwise.

The outer query against table `P` doesn't have any filters, so all the rows from this table will be considered for which the EXISTS predicate returns TRUE.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNAME -- Outer Query
FROM P
```

Now, the `EXISTS` predicate returns `TRUE` if the current row in table `P` has related rows in `SP Join S ON SP.SNO = S.SNO` where `S.STATUS > 25`

```
SELECT *
FROM SP Join S ON SP.SNO = S.SNO
WHERE SP.PNO = P.PNO -- Inner query
AND S.STATUS > 25
```

One of the benefits of using the `EXISTS` predicate is that it allows you to intuitively phrase English like queries. For example, this query can be read just as you would say it in ordinary English: select all `unique PNAME` from table `P` where at least one row exists in which `PNO` equals `PNO` in table SP and `Status in table S > 25`, provided table `SP` and `S` are joined based on `SNO`.

Answer (score 3):

Which SQL language are you using?

Either EXISTS return allways true or false or it allways returning rows, but in WHERE EXISTS... it will check returned rows > 0 (=>true).

Oracle, MySQL, PostreSQL:

> The EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered "to be met" if the subquery returns at least one row.
>   (http://www.techonthenet.com)

Answer (score 2):

your condition in where clause for main query

> SELECT DISTINCT PNAME FROM P

is dependent to Exist ,
if your subquery returns any rows ,
then exists returns true  ,otherwise it returns false
and the main query where clause return all of records in  p if Exists return true and nothing if it returns false